# org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Could not start a new session. Response code 500 error using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

A window appears after launch and immediately disappears, I can not understand what's wrong. Google except for the latest version, selenium is also set to the LATEST parameter (nothing changes with a specific version).

Error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Message:  Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created
```

Code:

[image: code]

Error:
[image: Error]

Comment: Please post text rather than links to images of text :)

Comment: Code in the form of images is not appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Update your chromedriver version, it seems your your browser and browser current driver version aren't same.

```
https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?
```

Comment: I downloaded the latest version namely 100.0.4896.20, 
need some other one?

Comment: I installed it before the last one and now it loads the site, but everything automatically closes automatically
now exitcode 0 instead of 1

Comment: ChromeDriver was started successfully.
мар 22, 2022 7:09:35 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
мар 22, 2022 7:09:35 PM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 99, so returning the closest version found: 97
мар 22, 2022 7:09:35 PM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
INFO: Found CDP implementation for version 99 of 97

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: download 97 
again does not work immediately as it was in the beginning

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Message:  Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created:
.
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
```

...implies that the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chrome=99.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v99.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/99.0.4844.51/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports Chrome version 99

- But your *chromedriver* version is not getting detected.

> Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver

- Your *JDK* version ***1.8.0_281*** is also old and ancient.

So most possibly there is a mismatch between *jdk version*, *chromedriver version* and the *chrome=99.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *JDK* is upgraded to current levels [JDK 8u311](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase8u211-later-archive-downloads.html).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v99.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=99.0.4844.51/) level.
- *Chrome Browser* is updated to  current *chrome=99.0* (as per [chromedriver=99.0.4844.51 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/99.0.4844.51/notes.txt)).

Answer (score 1):

If some one is on linux,

some distros install /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable, web driver manager tries to retry the version of chrome with the command

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome --version
```

Since that bin does not exists, is going to fail; The solution is very simple
just a simbolic link to google-chrome

```
# ln -s /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable /usr/bin/google-chrome
```

Answer (score 0):

More than an answer this continues with the question.

I'm using serenity-bdd with the following characteristics:

- Ubuntu:  22.04.1
- Google-Chrome: 106.0.5249.103
- Chrome driver: 106.0.5249.61

And the generated message error is:

```html
<<< ERROR!
net.thucydides.core.webdriver.DriverConfigurationError: Could not instantiate class org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Caused by: net.thucydides.core.webdriver.DriverConfigurationError: 
Could not instantiate new WebDriver instance of type class org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver (Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

Was trying with different driver combinations and none of them are working. Funny enough when i run on windows with the same configuration all works.

Comment: After long looking finally it is working, the solution was to define correctly the switches for chrome into the serenity.conf as follows:

chrome {
    switches = """--start-maximized;--test-type;--no-sandbox;--ignore-certificate-errors;--disable-popup-blocking;--disable-default-apps;--disable-extensions-file-access-check;--incognito;--disable-infobars,--disable-gpu"""
    capabilities.acceptInsecureCerts = true
}

Before the program couldn't identify the way to run it and that's why it was producing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Starting ChromeDriver 109.0.5414.74 (e7c5703604daa9cc128ccf5a5d3e993513758913-refs/branch-heads/5414@{#1172}) on port 48484
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: Failed to create Chrome process.
Host info: host: 'A-LAPTOP', ip: '192.***.0.***'
Build info: version: '4.7.2', revision: '4d4020c3b7'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.5'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [], extensions: []}}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [], extensions: []}}}]
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:148)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:106)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:67)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:156)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:167)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:142)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:535)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:228)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:156)
at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.(ChromiumDriver.java:101)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:82)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:50)
at com.project.skyfall.Browser_Drivers.main(Browser_Drivers.java:13)

Comment: I am stuck, kindly give the details.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have the exact same error. Out of the blue

Answer (score 0):

###### I resolved this issue by simply removing the `old_chrome` program stored in the `Temp` folder

```
C:\Users\<Your User>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Temp\scoped_dir
```

Answer (score -2):

In short, you need to install the previous version of the web driver with such a problem