# how to fix selenium session not created exception in azure devops pipeline

Tags: selenium-webdriver, azure-devops, selenium-chromedriver, azure-pipelines

My code is running perfectly on Eclipse in my local machine. But when I try to run the program on Azure devops pipeline, I get the below error.

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: 
Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

My Java version 11
Selenium version 4.17.0

I'm using latest Selenium manager webdriver

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Comment: Did you setup the local machine(working) as the self-hosted agent of DevOps? If not, please check if the versions of ChromeDriver, Selenium, and the Chrome browser is matched on the agent. In addition, did you check for `DevToolsActivePort` if it exists?
Please check the similar [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71571616/org-openqa-selenium-sessionnotcreatedexception-message-could-not-start-a-new-s), upgrade or link if needed.